# Use of unassigned local variable error #2

Tags: c#, .net, variables, scope

I've looked on google and other stackoverflow `Use of unassigned local variable` errors and I still cannot find the answer. I think that maybe my error is cause be misusing the scopes of ExtractionCtrl. I tried this code to test the scope and it works. So I don't know where is my mistake now.

**Testing the scope**

```
namespace RandomTesting
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 5;

            switch (x)
            {
                case 2:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Your # is 2");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Your # is :{0}", x);
                    x = x + 2;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Your # is :{0}", x);
                    break;
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Your # is :{0}", x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**PART OF THE MAIN CODE**

```
switch (arg)
{
    case "AR":
        ExtractionCtrl = new ARExtractionController();

        // add new mapping here
        break;

    case "ICN":
        ExtractionCtrl = new IcnExtractionController();

        // add new mapping here
        break;
}

int ticketID;
if (int.TryParse(arg, out ticketID))
{
    string returnedFilePath = ExtractionController.GetStartupPath();
    ExtractionCtrl.Extract(ticketID, returnedFilePath, AR_TEMPLATE_PATH, MAPPING_PATH);
}
```

Comment: was the value of `arg` actually "AR" or "ICN"?  Note the case sensitivity.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  If it's because `ExtractionCtrl` isn't assigned, then please post the code for where it is defined and where you assign it a value

Comment: If the value of arg is AR or ICN, why are you trying to do int.TryParse? Won't it always be false?

Comment: -arg is "AR"
- int.Tryparse : I know , sorry , I'm trying to modified someone else's code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your switch to set ExtractionCtrl does not have a default-case, so it is possible that ExtractionCtrl is not initalized after the switch. Since you do not show the declaration of ExtractionCtrl, I'm assuming it is declared without initialization:

```
SomeExtractionCtrlType ExtractionCtrl;
```

Hence the error.

Comment: Thank you!, wow I feel dumb and guilty of posting stupid questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need a `default` block in your `switch`.

```
switch (arg)
{
    case "AR":
        ExtractionCtrl = new ARExtractionController();

        // add new mapping here
        break;

    case "ICN":
        ExtractionCtrl = new IcnExtractionController();

        // add new mapping here
        break;
    default:
        ExtractionCtrl = new DefaultExtractionController();
        break;
}
```

Or you could initialize `ExtractionCtrl` when you define it.  I like the `default` option more, though.

Comment: If such a case should never happen, you could `throw` an exception there.  The compiler will understand that if that happens you can't ever reach the code that would use the variable for that case.

Comment: Well yeah, but I don't know his business rules at all.

Comment: I'm not saying he *must* throw an exception, merely that it's a viable alternative to using a default value if there isn't any acceptable default value.

Comment: But I dont need it right now, I'm focusing on the error message.

the arg is AR

Comment: Doesn't matter, the compiler sees that there are cases where you won't have initialized `ExtractionCtrl`, and that's why it's complaining.  If this was a runtime error, and `arg` was set to "AR", you'd be fine.  But this is a compile time error, so you have to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks, it took me sometime to realize it. I guess i'm slow.

Comment: We all overlook stuff, no worries!  Glad it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, this is a pretty common compile-time error, it means that the compiler thinks there's a chance the variable won't be initialized before it is called. What you should do is add a `default` case, as other answers say, but also initialize your variable when you declare it, either to `null`, or to the value you set it to in your `default`. Visual Studio is unfortunately very picky, and it doesn't see that all potential paths do end up granting a value.